# Writing code for new microcontroller/module without examples

Tags: embedded, programming, best-practice, industrial

I started learning embedded systems programming(after a long time when I stopped) and I see that most microcontroller boards/modules come with some set of example codes which can be used a base to create new projects.

my goal is to get job in embedded systems programming and I would like to know, do developers in the industry also use examples code as base ? If not, what is the industry practice?

Comment: There are different developers with different experience and needs.

Comment: ...and different ways of working.

Comment: Sometimes yes and sometimes no.  Sometimes we use base code to get drivers going faster, sometime we roll our own.  If you are learning, it's a great place to start.

Comment: Depends on industry. I would think making pacemaker software has stricter requirement for third party software than random toys.

Comment: One of the absolute hardest things is to get a 'blinky' or 'hello world' working with an unfamiliar toolchain and unfamiliar target device... I always prefer to start from *anything* that works at all and is buildable, rather than start a new embedded project from scratch. If I'm considering using a new target board, I expect/demand its docs include example code so that I can confirm (1) the toolchain is installed correctly so I can build firmware, (2) the device programmer works so I can run firmware, and (3) I can slowly modify their blinky/hello to shape it into a deliverable solution.

Comment: The hardest part of any microcontroller development is getting it to print  'Hello World', or flash a LED which is the equiivalent.

Comment: This is likely to be closed as opinion-based, but what I would often do it use the example code only for rough proof of concept or demo purposes before largely re-writing the necessary code to conform to my own and my company's rules & specifications for that sort of code.

Comment: If you're doing a bare-metal program you might start with example code, then throw it away. If you're doing something that has an RTOS, various and sundry middleware and drivers then you are probably going to retain a lot of code that is in the examples.

Comment: The the "industry practice" generally is to build up a codebase over many years, and not switch to an unfamiliar MCU. Example code may not be of much use because it is often incomplete or too application specific, and may have latent bugs that cause grief when you try to modify the code to suit your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I started learning embedded systems programming(after a long time when
> I stopped) and I see that most microcontroller boards/modules come
> with some set of example codes which can be used a base to create new
> projects.

The range of skills possessed by an audience for microcontroller programming is quite wide, these days. (The range was much smaller and had much higher requirements 30-40 years ago.)

You can look at this as a pyramid, of sorts. At the top of the pyramid you have experimental physicists, who possess a wide gamut of knowledge that includes profound mathematical, numerical, and complex analysis skills along with signal processing, operating system design and implementation, assembler, linker, and compiler design and coding, etc. These folks can literally fabricate a computer from the ground up. There aren't many of them. But they are highly skilled. At the bottom of the pyramid, with a much broader and larger base, you find people with the ability to code in higher level languages (or Excel) and pretty much little else. They can cobble up a UI program or an application running on Android using existing library stacks. But they could not design a practical sine function algorithm even if their life depended on it. They can use tools others have developed. But they would be hard-put to write anything novel on their own.

Sample/example code exists to address people more towards the bottom of the above pyramid. Those who need a basic model they can modify readily to achieve modest results on their own.

> my goal is to get job in embedded systems programming and I would like
> to know, do developers in the industry also use examples code as base
> ? If not, what is the industry practice?

All this depends on your own interests and life goals. Is programming "just a job to you?" A nine-to-five kind of thing that when you go home you completely forget about and go watch TV or mow the lawn? If so, you'll want a stable job with a company that can provide clear goals and only expects fixed hours from you and reasonable output from you given some salary they pay for it.

I tend to imagine, though, that embedded programmers generally are already above the bottom of the pyramid and are the kind of people who push themselves for more and work hard to reach towards higher levels. These people will want to understand how a compiler and a linker interact, for example, in some significant level of detail. They are the kinds of people who like the idea of actually writing their own operating system. Perhaps even trying their hand at a compiler and/or linker tool, too. And someone who wants to understand more about computer architecture and design. Maybe even try their hand at coding an MCU using VHDL or Verilog using an FPGA, just to see if they can do it.

---

All that said, the reality is that what counts as "embedded" depends on the application space.

If you need WiFi capability and need to support USB, you probably will want to use libraries that already provide these features for you and won't want to code them, yourself. (Thousands of pages of reading difficult text is a bit "much" if all you need to do is "get something done, quickly.") An ESP8266 or ESP32 is probably all you need here and you'd be more focused on just getting an application done. (*No assembly required.*) Here, example code can be very helpful.

If you need to achieve something that competes well on battery longevity, size, cost, volume, power, operation over wide temperature ranges, precision, calibrated accuracy, and many other complicated specification boundaries, then you will need a higher level of detailed understanding and will be using fewer libraries (perhaps none, at all) and will need the skills to develop almost all of the algorithms. In this case, example code will have almost no utility at all. All it will do for you is provide a quick way to make sure that you've installed all the necessary development tools, correctly, and that you can prove that you've got the basics in place.

---

So, decide who you want to be in the long term and what kind of goals you have in life. You can do very, very well for yourself without needing to learn much more than how to use existing libraries and leverage your coding upon the extensive work of others who have created the basic libraries you need. You can also do equally well for yourself if you pursue a greater level of detailed knowledge. I don't think one approach is better than another. And both are equally able to provide a good future.

The main difference is your competition. If you are looking at embedded applications that rely more on existing library systems and familiarity with common MCUs, such as the ESP32 for example, then you will be competing with many more people. If you focus on far more detailed knowledge, then your competition is smaller. But I don't think either of these provide significant differences in pay scale or levels of stress in getting the job done.

So just look at your own desires and decide who you are now and who you want to be, later. Then go for it.

There is no bright line approach, though. You choose who you are to become and then pursue that goal. You let the rest flow out of that decision.

Comment: Are you saying that developers which strive for higher levels of the skill-pyramid potentially let their lawn slide?

Comment: this is the answer i wanted to have. i am using ESP32 for iot development and I dont think i need to re-invent the libraries when I am mostly using wifi, bluetooth and cloud sdks.

Comment: But your answer made me more curious : Is bare-metal programming still a thing in industry https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/537623/is-bare-metal-programming-still-a-thing?

Comment: @po.pe No. I'm saying that if you are the kind of person whose work stops when the clock stops, you are not the kind of person who will be putting in the necessary study to maintain the necessary pace required to compete with others who do put in that time.

Comment: @Anudocs Yes. While the advancement in available MCUs and surrounding ICs and features continues at a fast pace, there remains a need for familiarity with assembly coding and how to integrate it within the use of libraries and higher level languages. I've never encountered a commercial/scientific instrument (which I specialize in) case where in order to provide competitive value that exceeded my competition didn't at least require some assembly. It may not be much. But I've always needed at least some in order to be the better product for our customers.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on your level of experience.

If you are a rookie at embedded systems programming, you'll be pretty lost without examples. It *is* possible to learn for example bare metal microcontroller programming without any examples by just reading the manual, but that assumes that you already have a solid grasp of C and a bit of assembler. And preferably also a computer- or electrical engineering degree, overall some 3-5 years of fooling around with programming in various forms.

Historically, we were never spoiled with examples. A new MCU was released and you'd have thousands of devs all re-inventing their own private wheel for that MCU, thousands of UART, SPI, ADC etc drivers developed in parallel. This is of course, a huge waste of everyone's time. Eventually the silicon vendors realized this and started to provide app notes and code examples. Unfortunately, every known silicon vendor out there can barely tell the difference between software and a bag of popcorn, so the quality of these examples are almost certainly of very poor quality even to this day. Including register maps, HAL libraries, CRT and so on.

You still have to read the friendly manual, but it is however a big time saver to just look at example code and grab the register setups from there. (Most of the work in developing a driver is getting all the hardware peripheral registers right.) Then you can tweak the code to your own needs and write it properly.