# Is bare-metal programming still a thing?

Tags: embedded, programming, library

I am in the learning phase of embedded systems programming. I am curious about the industry practices. Nowadays the microcontrollers are getting powerful and comes with a lot of memory, networking connectivity and own libraries and sdks.

So I would like to know that is bare-metal programming(without OS, libraries, sdks, frameworks) still a thing in industry? If yes, then till what extent abstraction is used?

Comment: It depends on the whole scenario obviously. You can do a small 8-bit MCU program from scratch in a day by using a datasheet because it is so simple you don't need any libraries, or you can spend weeks trying to get a 32-bit MCU even to go enable and configure all the internal modules to even blink a LED, which the vendor libraries would have done in 10 minutes. The practice will differ if you are doing a pacemaker, airbag or elevator kind firmware where it may not be allowed to use third party libraries for safety reasons or just some random generic products.

Comment: I understood your point. so 8-bit MCU still a thing in industry?

Comment: Of course 8-bit MCUs are still a thing. For example, do you think your computer mouse needs a 64-bit CPU to be efficient at what it needs to do? In automotive, the ECU and the multimedia system will certainly need to be beefy, but do you need all accessories (door locks, sliding windows, various controls, ...) to each have a 32-bit CPU with 1Gb RAM at their hand? Most of these accessories need to have a bit of "smartness" to avoid the wiring to become a hell, but the car manufacturer won't like it if he has to pay more than a few tens of cents for each of the CPUs that need to be there.

Comment: Like your previous question this is off topic as it is not specific and specifically answerable.  Your query belongs on a discussion forum, not an SE site.

Comment: @dim A computer mouse *could* be more economic to produce with an overkill 32-bit microcontroller and rapid software development in a language like Python, especially if it has some advanced features like Wi-Fi - you don't want to write your own Wi-Fi code, you want to borrow *someone else's* code that already works and requires a beefy microcontroller. Same reason why car multimedia systems run Linux. They don't *need* Linux but it's easier.

Comment: @user253751 Sure, I understand what you say. And I haven't said otherwise. But a *wifi mouse*? Dude, that's the worst example you could use. Does it exist? What's the purpose? So you can make it squeak if you ping it? I'll keep my mouse that can work for over a year on a AA battery, thanks.

Comment: @dim I don't know, but surely you've seen the trend to add more and more features into products. A wi-fi mouse is a silly example - point is, if you wanted to make one, you might not start with bare metal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I would like to know that is bare-metal programming(without OS, libraries, sdks, frameworks) still a thing in industry?

Yes! A lot depends on the application but small applications often don't need much processing power and this allows the use of small processors, sub $1 US.  A library or OS would force the use of a larger processor.  Another factor may be custom hardware: You still need to drive IC pins with the correct signals and timing is important. Often a commercial licence does not exist for this so you have to either create your own library (using bare metal code) or put it in your main program.

> If yes, then till what extent abstraction is used?

Libraries are often used for complex functions and supplied free by IC manufacturers.  Building an Ethernet TCPIPv4 stack from the bottom up or implementing USB are non trivial tasks so are often supplied as libraries or example source code.

A full TCPiPv4 Ethernet stack took me a year to develop from scratch.

Comment: for which microcontroller you developed TCP/IP stack?

Comment: NXP ARM  LPC2368

Answer (score 5):

The normal meaning of "bare metal" is *no operating system*. So all computer systems can roughly get categorized as either bare metal, RTOS or hosted system (full-blown OS). So "bare metal" doesn't necessarily mean microcontroller programming, even though that's the most common use for it - it could as well mean a x86 bootloader or some such. Or the hosted operating system itself.

If to program "bare metal", RTOS or hosted depends on the application and requirements. In particular, real-time or high integrity systems are always programmed bare metal or with RTOS.

As for microcontrollers, 8 bitters are unfortunately still widely used. Personally I've stopped using them and will never go back. However, modern ARM Cortex M is most often programmed "bare metal" as well. Same with DSP and various SoC that include a MCU core.

Answer (score 2):

> So I would like to know that is bare-metal programming(without OS, libraries, sdks, frameworks) still a thing in industry?

Yes, although for many medium-to-large microcontrollers things like [CMSIS](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/cmsis) save time.

> If yes, then till what extent abstraction is used?

Slightly confused by this, because "bare metal" means "without abstraction"; usually in C or occasionally directly in assembler. Especially for DSP work.

But this varies by project and context. Is it important that the program be as small and fast as possible? Tends to be bare metal. Lots of features, delivered quickly? Use more libraries. IoT systems in particular tend towards the latter; there's no value in writing your own networking and it's easy to make mistakes.

Comment: so CMSIS is an  hardware abstraction layer by ARM used for bare-metal programming?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "bare metal", but it's a library and therefore using CMSIS probably doesn't count as "bare metal" if you're being pedantic. Bare metal would be looking up the registers in the datasheet and explicitly writing them.

Comment: when a library <avr/io.h>  is used then basically they are giving names to ports and pins.  Using this kind of abstraction in programming will still be called bare-metal programming, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, I think so. This kind of thing is very subject to pedantry.